# D3 zoom on jquery button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a simple d3 svg zoom functionality. On double clicking the rectangle the zoom functionality is working fine.

Now i'm trying to implement the same functionality on a jquery button click function. But i'm getting following error in the console.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'translate' of null`
Following is my code.

```js
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 10])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var vis = d3.select("#svg-canvas").append("svg")
  .attr("width", "550")
  .attr("height", "200")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "svg-container")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,10)")
  .call(zoom);

vis.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .style("fill", "#444");

function zoomed() {
  d3.select(".svg-container").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#zoom").click(function() {
    zoomed();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-canvas">

</div>

<button id="zoom">
  Zoom
</button>
```

The functionality is not working. What am i doing wrong or is it possible to implement such functionality ?

Comment: Any errors on the browser console?

Comment: Yes, edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of the click you don't have d3.event set, because no events is comming from d3, hence you have to specify yourself the scale / translate parameters

```
function zoomClicked(translate, scale) {
    d3.select(".svg-container").attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
}

 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#zoom").click(function() {
         zoomClicked(4, 4);
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

D3 has its own event generating mechanism on double click. As you have the click handler on an element that is not handled by D3, you don't have a `d3.event`.

```
  d3.select(".svg-container")
    .attr("transform", scale(2)");
```